# how to not be dependent on the user's type sequence

Tags: c

Im trying to make a program in c that when the user type 3 different numbers, the program return the highest, the one in the middle and the lowest one, but its only working if the user type in a sequenced way`3,2,1` for example, i dont want it to be that way, any suggestions of how to prevent that?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){

    int number = 0;
    int highestNumber = 0;
    int middleNumber = 0;
    int lowestNumber = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        printf("type the %d number: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &number);

        if(number > highestNumber){
            highestNumber = number;
        }

        if(number < highestNumber && number < middleNumber){
            lowestNumber = number;
        }

        if(number < highestNumber && number > lowestNumber){
            middleNumber = number;
        }
        
    }

    printf("the highest number is: %d, the middle number is: %d and the lowest number is %d.", highiestNumber, middleNumber, lowestNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

i was expecting the code to return in the sequence that i typed on `printf()`, despite the typed order.

Comment: Can you provide concrete examples of different inputs & what output you want for each?

Comment: of course, just a second.

Comment: @ScottHunter ```type the 0 number: 0; type the 1 number: 2; type the 2 number: 4```, printed: ```the highiest number is: 12, the middle number is: 4 and the lowest number is 0.```, wanted it to be: ```the highiest number is: 12, the middle number is: 4 and the lowest number is 2.```

Comment: @ikegami thanks for clarification, gotta think about a solution for it now

Comment: I literally stated the solution in my comment, and it's now an answer.

Comment: A "good enough" solution to this is probably to use an array with 3 items, then apply "bubble sort" (google the term).

Comment: @Lundin, They are effectively doing a bubble sort if they replace the assignment with a swap as I suggested

Comment: The simplest way. Read the 3 values into an array. Apply qsort. Print. It may not be the best performing solution but it's simple and scaleable to any number of input values. Doing your "on-the-fly" update scales ver badly

Comment: Don't forget to test with equal numbers. Pretty sure there are bugs in that regard too.

Comment: @ikegami just made a ```if``` to prevent that too, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Say you previously entered `5` and you are now in the second pass of the loop. You've just entered `6`. Your variables look like this:

```c
int number         = 6;
int highiestNumber = 5;
int middleNumber   = 0;
int lowestNumber   = 0;
```

`number > highiestNumber` is true, so you enter the first `if`, and make `highiestNumber` equal to `6`. At the end of the first `if`, your variables look like this:

```c
int number         = 6;
int highiestNumber = 6;
int middleNumber   = 0;
int lowestNumber   = 0;
```

What happened to the `5` you previously entered? You just overwrote it!

When you replace the value of `highiestNumber` with the value of `number`, you should replace the value of `number` with the value of `highiestNumber`. This will push the old value down the list. This is missing.

Same idea with the other `if` statements.

---

There's also the issue that you accept signed numbers, but you consider `0` the lowest possible value. You should switch to using `unsigned` and `%u` instead of `int` and `%d`, or initialize your variables as follows:

```c
#include <limits.h>

int number;
int highiestNumber = INT_MIN;
int middleNumber   = INT_MIN;
int lowestNumber   = INT_MIN;
```

---

Finally, `highiestNumber` has one too many `i`.

Comment: would you mind including the code with the idea about what you said in: "you should replace the value of ```number``` with the value of ```highiestNumber```, if its not what @Support Ukraine intented in first ```if()``` they had made before editing.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the answer from @ikegami this code:

```
    if(number > highestNumber){
        highestNumber = number;
    }
```

is wrong as the previous highest number is lost.

In principle you need rather "ugly" code like

```
    if(number > highestNumber){
        lowestNumber = middleNumber;
        middleNumber = highestNumber;
        highestNumber = number;
    } else if(number > middleNumber){
        lowestNumber = middleNumber;
        middleNumber = number;
    } else if(number > lowestNumber){
        lowestNumber = number;
    }
```

Doing this "manual move of values" is a rather irritating, it's error prone (e,g, classic copy-paste-errors) and it scales badly if you some day want 5 or 10 input values.

I would recommend another approach.

- Read values to an array
- qsort the array
- Print the array

It's very simple code and it scales fine with any number of inputs just by changing a define.

like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Simply change this define for handling of other numbers of input
#define NUM_INPUTS 3

int cmp(const void * a, const void * b) {
    if (*(int*)a < *(int*)b) return -1;
    if (*(int*)a > *(int*)b) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int a[NUM_INPUTS];  // For high values of NUM_INPUTS use
                        // dynamic memory allocation
    
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_INPUTS; i++){
        if (scanf("%d", a+i) != 1) {
            // Add error handling here
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    qsort(a, NUM_INPUTS, sizeof a[0], cmp);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_INPUTS; i++){
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re "*You rather need code like*", no, just `swap( &number, &highestNumber );`. The subsequent `if` statements will handle the rest.

Comment: @ikegami when you say ```swap( &number, &highestNumber );``` its in the ```scanf()```?